# WCF behaves differently when hosted as service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I''m writing a WCF application with windows authentication. The problem is the authentication works properly when hosted in console but not working when hosted as windows service  Any reason behind this? The configuration is as below

```
       public static void start()
    {
        try
        {            
                       
            string strServerURL = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri(strServerURL);
            httpPostSeriveHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
            //Create the custom binding
            CustomBinding httpPostBinding = new CustomBinding();                
            // Prepare testmessage Encoding
            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement txtEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.None, Encoding.UTF8);
            txtEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
            txtEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
            txtEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
            txtEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
            txtEncoding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
            //Add textmessage encoding to custom binding
            httpPostBinding.Elements.Add(txtEncoding);
            //Add http transport to custom bindign
                HttpTransportBindingElement authobj = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
                authobj.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
                httpPostBinding.Elements.Add(authobj);                 
            httpPostSeriveHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new CustomBinding(httpPostBinding), string.Empty);
           // httpPostSeriveHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), httpb, string.Empty);
            httpPostSeriveHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host started @" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("\n\nService is Running as >> " + strServerURL);
            foreach (ServiceEndpoint se in httpPostSeriveHost.Description.Endpoints)
                Console.WriteLine(se.Address.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(httpPostSeriveHost.State.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to ensure the account used to run the service has rights to host an endpoint, usually admin but you want just the minimal permissions

Comment: Just curious: do you _have to_ use WCF?

Comment: @MickyD I can host the wcf service through windows service. The problem is windows authentication is not working when hosted as windows service

Comment: My point is that _everything_ acts differently when run as a Windows Service.  The fact that it works as a Console App proves little sadly.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific - what does it mean "windows authentication is not working" exactly? Any exception with a stack trace? Any entry in EventLog? Something crashes? etc.